# solr error in production, fine in development

Tags: solr, ckan

I'm searching on a CKAN site and I have this error from solr on test site, which I don't have on dev site

```
[Mon Jun 10 13:30:10.723687 2019] [:error] [pid 126661:tid 140082572949248] Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse '\xd7\x95\xd7\x95\xd7\xa2\xd7\x93\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa \xd7\x9c\xd7\x90\xd7\x95\xd7\x9e\xd7\x99\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa \xd7\x9e\xd7\x95\xd7\x9c\xd7\x9e\xd7\x95"\xd7\xa4 owner_org:"762ccf21-0422-4022-8c98-e47df9fb0a98"': Lexical error at line 1, column 72.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""]
[Mon Jun 10 13:30:10.724038 2019] [:error] [pid 126661:tid 140082572949248] Group search error: ('SOLR returned an error running query: {\\'sort\\': u\\'score desc, metadata_modified desc\\', \\'fq\\': [u\\'\\', u\\'+site_id:"default"\\', \\'+state:active\\'], \\'facet.mincount\\': 1, \\'rows\\': 21, \\'facet.field\\': [u\\'organization\\', u\\'groups\\', u\\'tags\\', u\\'res_format\\', u\\'license_id\\'], \\'facet.limit\\': \\'50\\', \\'facet\\': \\'true\\', \\'q\\': u\\'\\\\u05d5\\\\u05d5\\\\u05e2\\\\u05d3\\\\u05d5\\\\u05ea \\\\u05dc\\\\u05d0\\\\u05d5\\\\u05de\\\\u05d9\\\\u05d5\\\\u05ea \\\\u05de\\\\u05d5\\\\u05dc\\\\u05de\\\\u05d5"\\\\u05e4 owner_org:"762ccf21-0422-4022-8c98-e47df9fb0a98"\\', \\'start\\': 0, \\'wt\\': \\'json\\', \\'fl\\': \\'id validated_data_dict\\'} Error: SolrError(u\\'Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse \\\\\\'\\\\u05d5\\\\u05d5\\\\u05e2\\\\u05d3\\\\u05d5\\\\u05ea \\\\u05dc\\\\u05d0\\\\u05d5\\\\u05de\\\\u05d9\\\\u05d5\\\\u05ea \\\\u05de\\\\u05d5\\\\u05dc\\\\u05de\\\\u05d5"\\\\u05e4 owner_org:"762ccf21-0422-4022-8c98-e47df9fb0a98"\\\\\\': Lexical error at line 1, column 72.  Encountered: <EOF> after :
```

1. What does the error means?
2. What can I do to reproduce it on dev?
3. Which configuration may I missing from dev to test?

Thanks